# Unresolved external symbol error in jni call

Tags: c++, visual-c++, java-native-interface

There is some Issue with the JNI call. I have a `.cpp` file which inturn includes canon sdk.
My Java class `Check.java` has a declaration:

```
private native void check();
```

My `Check.cpp` file:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "iostream"
#include "EDSDK.h"
#include "Check.h"

using namespace std;

int check();    
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
typedef UINT (CALLBACK* LPFNDLLFUNC1)(DWORD,UINT);

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_Check_check  (JNIEnv *, jobject){
  check();
}

int check(){

HINSTANCE hDLL;               // Handle to DLL
LPFNDLLFUNC1 lpfnDllFunc1;    // Function pointer
hDLL = LoadLibrary("EDSDK.dll");
EdsError e = EdsInitializeSDK();
}
```

Basically my `Check.cpp` file is just Initializing the camera. On calling:

> cl -I "C:\jdk1.7\include" -I"C:\jdk1.7\include\win32" /EHsc -LD Check.cpp -FeCheck.dll

It throws the error

> Check.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _*imp*_EdsInitializeSDK@0
>   referenced in function "int __cdecl check(void)" (?check@@YAHXZ)

Similarly at calling any of the camera function, a similar error is thrown. What is the issue? As a standalone file `Check.cpp` works well.

Answer (score 0):

This error tells you that the linker is not able to resolve EdsInitializeSDK. This is not related to JNI. It's only related to the way you use your library. If you load it dynamically you have also to perfom the linkage manually. This means you have to use [GetProcAddress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683212%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to find the entry point of EdsInitializeSDK before calling it.

A side note about what you are doing here: You have to store `hDLL` somewhere were you can access it later in order to be able to do the cleanup (e.g. `FreeLibrary`) after the library is not needed anymore. Be careful with resource allocation (like `LoadLibrary`) in JNI layers because you have to free the resources allocated. Otherwise you'll get into hot water on the long run.